# Brew installing php packages after php is installed

Tags: macos, homebrew

Could someone explain me why in OSx brew not allow adding packages after php is installed, I mean, that I must installing imap with php:

```
brew install php56 --with-imap
```

Why is not available to install only imap if php is installed like:

```
brew install php-imap
```

Comment: Because nobody made that package; feel free to write it though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
brew reinstall php56 --with-imap
```